# the code that i've wrote works fine with a list of four elements but when the length of the list increases it is not giving the right answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a python code for a problem wherein I will be given with a list of string characters for example ["A", "B", "B", "C"] and the output that I should get is B and if there are more than one repeated value with equal number of repetitions or no elements in the list it should give"NONE" AS output. and my code is doing good so far but when the size of the list is increasing my code is giving wrong output please help me in optimizing the code so that it takes a list of any size and gives a correct output

```
    lis = ["A","B","B","A"]   #INPUT LIST
    catch = []
    final_catch=[]
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lis)):
            if lis[i] == lis[j]:
                catch.append(lis[i])
    
            
    final_catch =list(set(catch))
    print(final_catch)
    if len(final_catch)>=2 or len(final_catch) == 0:
        print("NONE")
    else:
        print(final_catch.pop())

# for input ["A,"B","B","A"] expected output:"NONE" actual output: "NONE"
# for input ["A","A","A","A"] expected output :"A" actual output : "A"
# for input ["A","A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B"] expected output : "B"
```

Comment: Your description is inconsistent. In the input `["A","A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B"]` _there are more than one repeated value_ and you say first _it should give"NONE" AS output_ and then `expected output : "B"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = ["A","A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B"]
>>> d = Counter(l)
>>> result = d.most_common() # result looks like [('B', 5), ('A', 4)]
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> result[0][0] if result[0][1] >2 else 'None' # conditional if-else statement
'B'
```

**Explanation:**

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to get number of occurrences of each element in a list

Use [.most_common()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to get list of most occurrence in the form of tuples`i.e., [(element, no. of occurrence)]`

> Return a list of the n most common elements and their counts from the
>   most common to the least

result[0][0] - we are passing index values to get first element of tuple in list.

result[0][1] - This gives you second element of tuple in a list.

*result[0] - select first element in a list

Comment: What would help to many if you could comment your code to explain what it is doing. Especially the `lambda` as this may not be 100% clear to readers. Furthermore: you can use `result = d.most_common()` no need for `sorted()` nor `lambda`

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo Thanks for suggestion. I have updated with explanation.